# Do I need to 'require' a file if it is already required by another file

Tags: node.js

I have 3 files

B requires A

C requires (B and A)

In this scenario does C needs to require A?
Doubt is because B is already requires A and when C requires B it should also requires A.

So I just want to be sure whether c needs to explicitly require A or not.

Upon the same situation, when I required explicitly A :

I found following error :

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'A'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/topi/controller.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Why this is so?

Comment: Read this http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases, yes. Each module that needs a reference to another module needs to `require()` it independently.

> Why this is so?

When you use:

```
var a = require('./a');
```

This declares `a` as local variable to the current module, which are all evaluated within their own [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). This is why modules have [`exports`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_exports) to allow them to specify their "*public*" API.

It can also be suggested that this is so that each module must list its dependencies, such as `c` depending on `a` and `b`.

```
// c.js
var a = require('./a');
var b = require('./b');
```

But, you could use `exports` to *pass-along* one module through another -- e.g. `a` through `b`:

```
// b.js
var a = exports.a = require('./a');
```

```
// c.js
var b = require('./b');

console.log(b.a);
```

And, technically, you could also attach `a` to [`global`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global). Though, generally you shouldn't. Doing so is typically considered a code smell.

Comment: exactly . very well discribed

Answer (score 0):

yes you need its work as a individual the class system of node.js is different then other server side or oop languages  .

```
var a = require('./a');


 var b = require('./b');
```

Have to do this